# Wordpress overwriting span

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Uploaded this css & html to a Wordpress site running twenty-twelve theme and my  are running vertically down my div's. I cannot figure out why or how to fix this.

to see the problem the link is http://www.pacificexpress.com.au/products

```
<style> 
    .productContainer {
        border: 1px solid black; 
        width: 900px; 
        height: 305px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .productContainer a img, .productContainer a img h2 p { 
        float: left; 
        display:block; 
        margin-bottom: -40px;
    } 

    .productContainer a img { 
        height: 300px; 
        width: 300px; 
        margin-right: 15px; 
    } 


    .productContainer p { 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        text-decoration-line: none; 
        color: #A1c6E3; 
    }

    .productContainer span {
        font-size: 24px; 
    }


</style>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/rapid-worker/'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/BowFrontDesk_pacificexpresscopy_zps7e8dc151.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Rapid Worker <br/> </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>
</div>

<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=975'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/Corner_work_station_zps644dc92c.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Rapid Span<br/>  </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>

</div>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=971'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/corner_workstationcopy_zps1ff2c6b7.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Rapid Manager<br/>  </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>
</div>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=978'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/chair_mesh_am100_zps582ba090.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Seating <br/> </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>
</div>
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://goo.gl/M1nY2j'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/tamboor_cupboard_zps0e8c0f6c.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Steel Storage <br/> </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>
</div>

<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=982'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/Screen_zps64d2ea85.jpg'/>
            <p><span> Screens<br/>  </span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a></li>
</div>
```

thanks

James

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: I cannot get my span elements to sit above my <p>. It automatically runs vertically down the left hand side of my page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please follow below html structure take span outside of p tag

```
<div class='productContainer'>
    <a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/rapid-worker/'>
        <img src='http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m215/furnxfurniture/Photobucket%20Desktop%20-%20Jamess%20MacBook%20Air/Furnx%20Images/Front%20Page%20Images/BowFrontDesk_pacificexpresscopy_zps7e8dc151.jpg'/>
            <span> Rapid Worker</span>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the CSS used:

```
.entry-content p {
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;
}
```

**remove the property display: inline-flex; from above and you will get the desired output.**

```
.entry-content p {
        /*display: inline-flex;*/
        float: left;
    }
```

[image]